# Is my websocket session idea practical?

Tags: node.js, authentication, session, websockets

In a situation where all communication (including logging in) between a client (web browser) and server is done over a persistent TLS encrypted websocket, would there be anything inadvisable about having the server attach the client's log-in state to the connection itself as custom properties?

ie,

```
WSconnection.loggedIn = true;
WSconnection.timeout = Date.now() + 360000;
```

By doing this you'd actually be authenticating the *connection* not the user. However, the connection is a persistent TLS encrypted point to point connection.

Comment: I guess an obvious disadvantage would be if the connection closes abnormally, the client would needs log in again. However, in my own small tests, I haven't seen websocket connections close abnormally.

Answer (score 2):

That is how HornetQ's websocket implementation works (Stomp doesn't necessarily have to work over WebSockets but HornetQ exposes both naked TCP and WebSocket options).

[StompConnection.java](https://github.com/hornetq/hornetq/blob/master/hornetq-protocols/hornetq-stomp-protocol/src/main/java/org/hornetq/core/protocol/stomp/StompConnection.java)

Essentially the connection object is wrapped with the metadata of the HornetQ session ID and the login credentials and flagged "isValid".

So yes, it's certainly a practical and workable method.